# Не срабатывает overflow-x: scroll при уменьшении окна просмотра

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы блок можно было скролить при окне, меньшем размера блока с фоном.

```
<div class="bg-location">

</div
```

```
.bg-location {
    width: 1680px;
    height: 940px;

    background: #fff url("../img/bg/bg-location.jpg") no-repeat;

    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда вот так:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.bg-location {
  width: 1680px;
  height: 940px;
  background: #fff url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKuUl.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="bg-location"></div>
</div>
```

Или так:

```css
.bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bg-location {
  width: 1680px;
  height: 940px;
  background: #fff url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKuUl.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="bg-location"></div>
</div>
```